# Error trying to create file in OneDrive directory instead of local user drive

Tags: inno-setup, onedrive

My installer includes lines for adding folders and files to the {userdocs} area.

```
Source: "FolderName\*"; DestDir: "{userdocs}\{#MyAppName}\FolderName"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs
```

However, some users have received an error while installing.

"An error occurred while trying to create a file in the destination directory:
Setup was unable to create directory "C:\Users\[username]\OneDrive\?????????
Error 123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Why is the installer trying to install on OneDrive rather than the local folder? It may be that the OneDrive account is full, but why would that prevent the completion of the installation locally? Is it possible for {userdocs} to return a OneDrive folder?

Comment: It's easy to test: `Log(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}'));`

Comment: It is not uncommon. In my own software I find it hard to write data directly to a shared folder. More often than not I have to copy manually from a nother location to that folder myself. I don't know if you are suffering the same issue.

Comment: Note that I cannot reproduce the error myself. This is happening with a few end users.

Comment: "Why is the installer trying to install on OneDrive rather than the local folder?" I suppose because the end user has redirected their 'documents' folder?

Comment: I have sent the user a version that displays the userdocs location as described by Martin above. It returns a OneDrive folder. So I guess he must have redirected it as you said.